# How to use Futon and push a couchapp to a CouchDB which uses a vhost?

Tags: couchdb, couchapp, couchdb-futon

I have a CouchDB server which hosts a small website. For this reason, I set up a vhost section in the CouchDB configuration, so that a request to:

domain.com

will be "re-written" to

domain.com/site/_design/app/_rewrite

... as explained in [this post](http://blog.couchbase.com/what%E2%80%99s-new-apache-couchdb-011-%E2%80%94-part-one-nice-urls-rewrite-rules-and-virtual-hosts) and as I wanted, so I can keep "pretty" URLs. And that works fine!
However, after doing this, I am not able to access Futon on the same hostname.
That is not so inconvenient, but I found out that I cannot even push my couchapp anymore.
As I use a server that lives "in the cloud" (forgive the jargon) I have no other hostname I can use to push or access admin stuff. Is there anything I can do to fix that?
I have tried several rewrite rules, including

"from": "*", "to": "../../*"

but this will not work (requests to "/_all_dbs" end up in "site/_all_dbs".... and adding one more ../ to the "to" string causes CouchApp to complain it's an unsafe rewrite rule.

Any hints appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have `{"from": "db/*", "to": "../../../*"}` among my rewrites, I changed `secure_rewrites` to `false` under the httpd section on the configuration page in the Futon interface to get it to work.

Futon is accessable under `http://hostname/db/_utils` and I can push to `http://hostname/db/databasename` using CouchApp. Except for some minor Futon bugs it seems to work fine, but admittedly I haven't tested it for long.

I hope this helps!

Comment: How insecure is it to turn this option off, by the way?

Comment: Thank you for your hint, but I am not able to change the CouchDB configuration in Cloudant. So this will not work for me.

Comment: Oh, well... answer accepted as it's probably the only way (other than turning off the vhost while you do admin stuff) to get this done.

Answer (score 0):

Can you get the ip? I know with aws you can. Then couchapp push .

Comment: I am using Cloudant... it's probably just a virtual server... don't think I can get an IP.